# Load on load balancer

Tags: tcp, load-balancing

In our TCP servers deployment, we have load balancer to which all clients initially connect. Then load balancer gives each of them actual server IP address to which they are suppose to connect. Client then disconnects from load balancer and proceeds with TCP connection to the server IP address they've got. Thus, load is being distributed amongst servers.

This arrangement works perfectly well for thousands of connections. But we are worried if this would work for millions of number of connections? Load balancer itself will not be able to cater server IP address to all those clients in timely manner, is what our nightmare. What are alternatives here?

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the load balancer you are using on whether it can cater or not. Some load balancers can do millions of L4 connections. Also I don't think that having connections go direct to the server is a good idea because what happens to the connections if the server becomes unavailable. I would keep all traffic going to the load balancer. You could also consider Direct Server Return which is where requests from clients go through the load balancer and responses go direct to the client (bypassing the load balancer).